# Converting Datetime picker to UTC time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am trying to standardise the time the database gets from a the bootstrap time date form, however I am getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: e.date.getTime is not a function

When I print out `e.date` it is `Wed Jul 15 2015 16:30:51 GMT+1200`

I am attempting to follow this guide, but I have had to change a few things to get this far.http://jsfiddle.net/TC6Gr/37/

```
$('#start_time').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss a',
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    alert(e.date);
    $('#start-time-before').html(e.date); // Log
    var TimeZoned = new Date(e.date.setTime(e.date.getTime() + (e.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)));
    $('#end_time').datetimepicker('setStartDate', TimeZoned);
    $('#start_time').datetimepicker('setDate', TimeZoned);
    $('#start-time-adjusted').html(TimeZoned); // Log
});
```

Comment: Which language are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: Or maybe you can do this server-side.

Comment: Why do you have `dp.change` as the event instead of `changeDate` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this line

```
new Date("2018/10/10 09:27");
```

This can create a Date object. You will return  Date object's getTime() or valueOf() functions with the UTC timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this instead.

```
 var offset = e.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
 var now = e.date.getTime();
 var utc = now + offset;
 var TimeZoned = new Date(utc);
```

Comment: To calculate UTC you need to substract the offset. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC

Answer (score 0):

Does this result in what you are trying to do?

Change this line:

```
$('#start-time-adjusted').html(TimeZoned);
```

to:

```
$('#start-time-adjusted').html(TimeZoned.toUTCString());
```